# cordova-plugin-root-detection validation before apk installation

Tags: javascript, cordova, plugins

I am trying to make my Cordova cross-platform check for root access before allowing it to be installed on rooted device? Is it possible to do that using Crodova?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do any sort of checking before allowing an app to be installed - that's putting the chicken before the egg: you can't run logic in code that hasn't been installed.

The best you can do is to check if the device has been rooted immediately on app startup and if so, don't allow use of the app (e.g. exit or display error message).